# How to stop Adobe Illustrator CC from changing spaces to hyphens?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, save

Illustrator is changing my filenames as such when I use Save for Web:

`My File.png` → `My-File.png`

The old Illustrator had a Unix checkbox in the Save to Web export settings, but new Illustrator doesn't.

Here's a screenshot of the equivalent setting in Photoshop:
[image: SaveForWeb]

[image: UnixSetting]

Here is what the function looked like before, in an older version:
[image: UnixCheckbox]

Comment: I'd be interested to learn if this were possible as well!

Comment: Me too. It's infuriating & the new export that supposedly replaced it is a poor alternative, as it discards EXIF data, with no option to preserve it. [oops, sorry, I'm thinking Photoshop, but it's a similar issue]

Comment: @Tetsujin I think in Photoshop, in Save for Web, if you click on one of the settings menus in the upper-right corner of the Save for Web window, there's a scheme dropdown where you can remove Unix or something. I did this before, but I don't have PS right now so I can't tell you the exact wording.. but look for it! It should be there... in Photoshop.

Comment: @Noko - I found it, thanks. Fixed. It's in Edit Output settings > Saving files, same as the old version, just with the new look. BTW, you can specify export sizes precisely, but only on the right side, not in the list of exports on the left. I do think that Export panel is only half finished :\

Answer (score 1):

Save for Web adheres to **[standard web server file naming conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488280/what-are-the-legal-allowed-characters-for-web-server-file-names-on) ([2](https://ed.fnal.gov/lincon/tech_web_naming.shtml), [3](https://www.mtu.edu/umc/services/digital/writing/characters-avoid/))**.

- No spaces
- No odd characters
- Max file name length

Whenever you violate one of these, Save for Web corrects it. i.e. substitutes hyphens for spaces, removes odd characters, truncated file names.

This is done so that the file name itself isn't a problem on a web server. Since, after all, Save for Web assumes the files are *for the web* and thus a web server.

If you really want to use spaces, odd characters, long file names, etc. then **don't** use Save for Web. Export instead. Or change the file names in the Finder/Windows Explorer after saving them.

*(I have no clue what "Unix checkbox" you are referring to. Iv'e never seen any such checkbox It may exist, but to the best of my knowledge not in the Save for Web Dialog.)*

Comment: I can't use Export in my use case because it doesn't let you specify a size. I need to export my artwork in several smaller sizes, and even Export for Screens doesn't support 1/3 and 2/3 sizes (iOS requires 2x and 3x, so I need 0.33333x and 0.66666x options to get from my base 300x300 canvas to sizes 100 and 200.) I'd also like to specify exact size.

("Unix checkbox" is something in Photoshop's Save for Web preferences. It has a settings menu where you can specify whether or not to use the Unix naming scheme. I don't have PS right now so I can't post a screenshot, but it solves this issue.)

Comment: I modified my original post to show a screenshot of the setting in Photoshop. By unchecking "Unix" you could get the spaces to show up again. Even though "Save for Web" assumes saving for web, the key functionality & reason for my using it is the capability of specifying sizes and such. Whether or not web servers expect it, it shouldn't clobber my own names.

Comment: Well, my personal opinion is.. you shouldn't be using spaces in jpg, png, gif, or svg file names for any reason.... You can't tell me that "My_File.png" is more difficult to read than "My File.png" -- one *may* cause issues, the other will not. Use underscores.. hyphens, etc. Wether or not spaces present a problem for you right now, this minute, with today's software, means very little if a year from now spaces suddenly become very problematic. But. to each his (or her) own.

Comment: My issue is that I use these files for direct upload to my own Photography site... which uses the filename as the image description [& the exif data for the camera details, which precludes the useless new 'Export' page]. Underscores are ugly so I have to then manually remove them using their web interface. Killing them at source is far easier.

Comment: Fair enough. I get that. If the file name is used as an image description, it's a shame they merely didn't process the file name text and strip hyphens, underscores, etc from it. Much easier that way (and safer considering site may change servers from time to time). On my site (i built myself), I purposefully created a php loop to strip suffixed and odd characters then transform all lower case to title case. Easy operation under the hood while still uploading all lowercase, no spaced, files. -- Still I do understand. We all do what we need to do.